# get view in a fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am learning Android.
From my activity, I creates a fragment

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction = 
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 MessageFragment fragment = new MessageFragment();
 transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
 transaction.commit();
```

The fragment has two tabs

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
  // Inflate a new layout from our resources
  View view;
  if (position ==0) {
         view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.message_item,
                        container, false);
                // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
                container.addView(view);
   }
   else {
       view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.setting_item,
                        container, false);
          // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
          container.addView(view);
      }

 // Return the View
  return view;
}
```

For both layouts, there is a textview with same id (say MessageTitle), in my MainActivity, I have a LocalBroadcastManager to pass some messages. When message type is warning, I would like to update the textview in message_item layout and when message type is setting, then update the textview in setting_item.

So I can I get the view that is on display so I can update the textview accordingly? Or maybe it is better to give unique id for individual textviews?

Many Thanks

Comment: Use ViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

A recommended approach would be to use `ViewPager`. But there are a lot of not-so-normal approaches in your existing code itself, so I would simply go ahead and try to help you with your immediatte question

You do not need to get the active root fragment `View`. What you really need is the active `TextView`.

You can use a class variable `mMessageTextView` and initialize it inside the `instantiateItem()` method using `mMessageTextView = view.findViewById(<the id of the texti view>)`. Further, you can have a boolean variable `isSettginsPage` and set it `True/False` as per what is active now.

When you recieve the message from the `LocalBroadcastManager` simply use the `isSettingsPage` to know what page is active now and then if required, update the `mMessageTextView` as `mMessageTextView.setText(<message>)`.

Comment: hi, do you have examples with using ViewPager? All I want is an example which has two tabs and different tab has different textviews. So I can understand how to set them properly

Comment: You will never find like exact example, but you will find a lot of useful tutorials on google.